# How can I find Kairos rock in dragonvale on Kindle?

Tags: dragonvale

I am tt level 20, but the Kairos rock is not in the store. I have tried updating, but there is no update available for Kindle. What else can I do to get the Kairos rock?

Comment: What OS is on your Kindle?

Comment: Perhaps it is your Kindle; I have a Kindle Fire too, and I got it just fine :/

Answer (score 1):

I got mine at level 21. Maybe that's your problem :)